# ClassNotfoundActivity when updating System App Android

Tags: android

We are an Android software company and we have a problem with the update of a system application.
Original app which is preinstalled in some devices was developed by another company. 
Now we have published our application in google play with the same key and the same package but we have a problem with android 2.3 devices. 
When users update their apps, it crashes with next log message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.es/com.yyy.es.activities.InitialActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.yyy.es.activities.InitialActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/app/xx_v1.0.1_android-generic_es.apk]
```

It seems that is trying to open activity in the old apk instead of in the newest one, which is in `/data/app`.
If users clear app data, the problem continues. The only way to fix it is to reboot the device.

I have seen that the manifest android of the old apk has: android:persistent=true but the new apk doesn't have it. 
We can't test it very often because the market signature is from another company so we have to search a solution without tests which is very dificult.

Please, could you help us?

Thank's a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you using some tools like ProGuard to obfuscate the code?

Comment: No, I'm not obfuscating the code. If I reboot the phone the updated app works well so I think that's not the problem :(